# Webpack/React - How To Hot Reload A Separate Package

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-hot-loader

I am using webpack and react. I have an app and I have a component library that I import into the app.

In the component library index.js I export each component individually

```
export componentA from './ComponentA';
export componentB from './ComponentB';
```

In my app I import the components from the lib

```
import { componentA } from 'componentLib';
```

**How can I hot reload component A?** Currently I get

`The following modules couldn't be hot updated: (Full reload needed)
This is usually because the modules which have changed (and their parents) do not know how to hot reload themselves`

**Update 1**

So the following works with caveats.. This seems to act as a catch all and will re-render everything, however it breaks other hot updates like from `module.hot.accept('./sagas', () => {...})`. It says the sagas still update, but the changes aren't reflected. So this won't work long term

```
  module.hot.accept();

  if (shouldBreak) {
    shouldBreak = false;
  } else {
    const nextRoot = require('containers/Root').default; //eslint-disable-line
    render(nextRoot);
  }
```